# Alternatives to deprecated `scala.collection.script` in scala 2.11?

Tags: scala, deprecated, scala-collections, scala-2.11

`scala.collection.script` seems to get deprecated with scala 2.11 without suggested alternatives. Given that observable collections are very useful in GUI programming I don't quite understand this step. I agree that immutable data structures are to be preferred almost everywhere but when syncing between a view and a viewmodel the advantages of an observed mutable structure are clear.

What are suggested alternatives if one needs to observe changes in a mutable scala collection? I have created a mixin trait in the past to achieve that myself but that is very cumbersome because you don't know for sure which methods are implemented (as in overridden) and which are derived from the big number of mixed-in traits from the collection library which means that there is no general solution to capture all changes in every type of collection. Also those implementation details might change anytime in the future so I would rather not maintain something like this myself.

If anybody could point me to a suitable alternative, that would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Deprecated with no direct replacement.

See commit:

Collections library tidying, part one: scripting.

Everything in scala.collection.scripting is deprecated now, along with the
<< method that is implemented in a few other classes.  Scripting does not
seem used at all, and anyone who did can easily write a wrapper that does
the same thing.

https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/3cc99d7b4aa43b1b06cc837a55665896993235fc